# Dealing with multiple JUnit test cases

Tags: selenium, junit

I'm writing JUnit test cases using the selenium web driver, and I'm running into issues when trying to make multiple tests in one file.  Here is an example of my code structure:

```
public class exampleScripts extends SeleneseTestCase {

   public void setUp() throws Exception{
      SeleniumServer seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer();
      seleniumServer.start();
      setUp("https://my.target.URL", *firefox");
    }

   @Test
   public void test1() throws Exception {

       //do test stuff

       try {
           //check if results are good
       }

       catch (Throwable e) {
           //handle error
       }

   }

   @Test
   public void test2() throws Exception {

       //do more test stuff

       try {
           //check results
       }

       catch (Throwable e) {
           //handle error
       }
  }
}
```

Now, the tests by themselves work correctly, but I am getting the error `Failed to start: SocketListener1@0.0.0.0:4444` when running my class as a whole.  The first test runs correctly, but the second I move on to the next test, it seems like it's trying to re-start the session, when I just want it to continue on the old session.  How do I get around this issue?

Comment: The only solution I could find was shutting down the server in my code, but I just want to continue my operations once the first test is finished.  My website is password protected, so I don't want to keep entering my credentials after every test.

Comment: Do you mean you are manually entering your credentials each time?

Comment: I think your `setUp()` method need to call one of the `setUp` methods in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was able to find a wonky work-around for this problem, though I wouldn't recommend this to others as a solution.  I created a test_suite function to run all my tests, and log the results myself.

```
public void setUp() {
   //setUp stuff
}

public void testAll() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("my/target/path");
    test1();
    test2();
}

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    //test stuff
   try {
       //check results
   }

   catch (Throwable e)  {
       log.INFO("There was an error in test1");
   }
 }

 //and so on
```

The whole test suite would be run on testAll().  Again, would not recommend this solution, as it does not take advantage of JUnit's logging, but it worked for me.